# What are the dll files that Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable package extracts?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, package, redistributable

Aside from `msvcrxxx.dll` (where `xxx` represents the runtime version, example `msvcr100.dll`), what are the other dll files that `Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable package` extracts?

Comment: there's an unpacked version of the redist in the visual studio directory, e.g. on my machine at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.28.29325\x64`

Comment: IDK if the distributable installer downloads files, but if it doesn't, sometimes you can open those files with 7zip and explore what's there.

Comment: The list of redistributables depends on the version, for example there is no `msvcr*.dll` since VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

| Glob Pattern | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `vcruntime*.dll` | Runtime Library for native code |
| `vccorlib*.dll` | Runtime Library for managed code |
| `msvcp*.dll` | C++ Standard Library for native code |
| `concrt*.dll` | Concurrency Runtime Library for native code |
| `mfc*.dll` | Microsoft Foundation Classes (MFC) Library |
| `mfcmifc80.dll` | MFC Managed Interfaces Library |
| `mfcm*.dll` | MFC Managed Library |
| `mfc*u.dll` | Unicode MFC libraries end in "u" |
| `vcamp*.dll` | AMP Library for native code |
| `vcomp*.dll` | OpenMP Library for native code |

A somewhat less precise but more concise glob pattern is `vc* msvc* mfc* concrt*` -- that will tend to pick up some unrelated files, but fits neatly on a command line, so you can do things like:

```
CD C:\Windows\System32
DIR vc* msvc* mfc* concrt*
```

Per Microsoft, "Determining Which DLLs to Redistribute"
(Undated page, accessed 2021 SEP 01)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/determining-which-dlls-to-redistribute?view=msvc-160